# Trying to pin custom cell to bottom of UITableViewController to use as a footer

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm  using this code to display my custom footer:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("footerCell") as! FooterTableViewCell
    return cell
}
```

However, when I reach the bottom of the table the custom footer cell detaches and bounces from the bottom. How can I make the other cells bounce but the footer cell sticky? Is there an easy way to do this in interface builder?

Ideally I'd like to not have to embed or subview the tableviewcontroller. Thanks! CHM

Comment: No, I don't think there is. Even using the tableview footer (which is not the same as the section footer) with autolayout constraints won't work. An easy hacky approach would be use a regular VC, add the TV as a subView, add a blank (empty) footer of the right size, and then add the real footer as a subview of the main view (i.e. a sibling of the TV). Then drive the animation using constraints and the didScroll callback on the TV

Comment: @RichTolley Considering the amount of apps that use footers, you'd think apple would have this built right into interface builder or something